# Tracking objects using javaCV

Tags: tracking, javacv

I am trying to track faces using Camshift in JavaCV. I have found Open CV equivalent at:

https://gist.github.com/231696

I have been successfully able to convert much part of the code, but struggling to figure out the equivalent of the following in JavaCV. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
TrackedObj* obj;

if((obj = malloc(sizeof *obj)) != NULL) {

obj->hsv  = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 3);
obj->mask = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
obj->hue  = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
obj->prob = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we can define a `class` similar to the `struct TrackedObj` like this:

```
class TrackedObj {
    IplImage hsv;
    IplImage hue;
    IplImage mask;
    IplImage prob;
    CvHistogram hist;
    CvRect prev_rect;
    CvBox2D curr_box;
}
```

And we can translate the bit of code you point out in a very similar fashion like this:

```
TrackedObj obj = new TrackedObj();
obj.hsv  = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 3);
obj.mask = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
obj.hue  = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
obj.prob = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 1);
```